# Bing Site Scan; Redirecting to login page

Tags: search, search-engines, bing

My website apkeh.com is not getting indexed, it says violation of community guidelines. I don't know what guidelines, exactly I am violating. I tried a site scan and found that most of the links are redirecting to login page for example,
apkeh.com/loginpage/?redirect_to=https:%2F%2Fapkeh.com%2Fworld-of-tanks-blitz-mod-apk-unlimited-gold-2022%2F
with error

*ERROR : Meta Description tag missing*

I have checked the posts are not private and the rankmath plugin has no specific restrictions on posts. Similar one posts is also detected by Google Search Console however most of the urls are fine in Search Console. Only the posts are getting redirected while pages are not. I have submitted sitemap and the sitemap has the correct urls. Please suggest what could be causing the link to redirect? Any Community guidelines rules that I am violating?

Comment: Did you publish an article on your website about World Of Tanks Blitz mods, or did something malicious put it there?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes, I have put World of Tanks Bilts mods. But I see the same mods and similar text is present on too many sites. However, I did not put any other malicious things.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Those websites and corresponding pages are indexed in Bing. But, I am more concerned why my website links are redirected to the login page in site scan?